# PHP Method to detect area of a PNG that is not transparent

Tags: javascript, php

Im looking to convert a Javascript function that has been written to detect the non-transparent area of an image.

[The initial question and answer is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255825/javascript-method-to-detect-area-of-a-png-that-is-not-transparent)

The iteration is easily converted to PHP, however im having trouble obtaining the same image data as written here: (getImageData and Uint32Array)

```
var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h),      // get image data for canvas
buffer = idata.data,                       // get buffer (unnes. step)
buffer32 = new Uint32Array(buffer.buffer), // get a 32-bit representation
x, y,                                      // iterators
x1 = w, y1 = h, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
```

Is there a method in which I can get the same data with PHP? The Javascript method given has browser compatibility issues in which I have solved by writing a node application. I would prefer to have a PHP method if at all possible.

Comment: php (at least gd) doesn't handle pixels like in javascript. You typically would have to loop over the x/y and use [imagecolorat](http://www.php.net/imagecolorat) and the x/y coords to get a specific pixel's color data.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate with a working example? Ive tried using imagecolorat but im very unfamiliar with the results and am unsure about sorting the RGB/Alpha bits to iterate correctly.

Comment: There is an example in the manual of how to use `imagecolorat()`. You would just get the height/width of the image and loop over and get the color at each pixel with a nested for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img_file);

    if (!ctype_xdigit($hex)) $hex = imagecolorat($img, 0,0);
    $b_top = $b_lft = 0;
    $b_rt = $w1 = $w2 = imagesx($img);
    $b_btm = $h1 = $h2 = imagesy($img);

    do {
        //top
        for(; $b_top < $h1; ++$b_top) {
            for($x = 0; $x < $w1; ++$x) {
                if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_top) != $hex) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        // stop if all pixels are trimmed
        if ($b_top == $b_btm) {
            $b_top = 0;
            $code = 2;
            break 1;
        }

        // bottom
        for(; $b_btm >= 0; --$b_btm) {
            for($x = 0; $x < $w1; ++$x) {
                if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_btm-1) != $hex) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        // left
        for(; $b_lft < $w1; ++$b_lft) {
            for($y = $b_top; $y <= $b_btm; ++$y) {
                if(imagecolorat($img, $b_lft, $y) != $hex) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        // right
        for(; $b_rt >= 0; --$b_rt) {
            for($y = $b_top; $y <= $b_btm; ++$y) {
                if(imagecolorat($img, $b_rt-1, $y) != $hex) {
                    break 2;
                }
            }

        }

        $w2 = $b_rt - $b_lft;
        $h2 = $b_btm - $b_top;
        $code = ($w2 < $w1 || $h2 < $h1) ? 1 : 0;
    } while (0);
```