# Finding non transparent filled areas in images on javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I've an image with some filled circles, rectangles etc. I want to find x1,x2, y1, y2 areas of filled areas.

[Javascript Method to detect area of a PNG that is not transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255825/javascript-method-to-detect-area-of-a-png-that-is-not-transparent)

Accepted answers works fine but i need to find each areas separately. As in the image below, i need thee x1, x2, y1, y2 positions. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Will the shape be of uniform color and fully opaque?

Comment: Color of image part will not be uniform. But all other areas will be completely transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline to get you started:

1. Use `context.getImageData` to get the pixel data from the canvas,
2. Scan the pixel data for the first non-transparent pixel,
3. Use the "marching squares" algorithm to find the border path points around the circle or rectangle: [Draw border around nontransparent part of image on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207232/draw-border-around-nontransparent-part-of-image-on-canvas/28220510#28220510),
4. Iterate the path points and find the [minX,minY] & [maxX,maxY]. This the bounding box of the circle or rectangle.
5. Erase the bounding box area calculated in step#4 so that you can look for the next shape.
6. Go back to step#1 until you've determined the bounding boxes of all non-transparent shapes on the canvas.

Comment: 4. Iterate the path points and find the [minX,minY] & [maxX,maxY]. This the bounding box of the circle or rectangle.
How can i detect the rectangles with such points? It returns all non-transparent points as far as i understood.

Comment: Step#3 will return a set of points that form a path around the first non-transparent shape. So finding the min's and max's of that set of points will give you the bounding box of that shape. ;-)

Comment: How can i clear a rectangle on canvas? Is there any method to clear canvas like clear(x1, y1, x2, y2) ?