# Print out section of html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, printing, html5-canvas

I have a html5 canvas (3000px x 3000px). I am using the following function to print the canvas:

```
function printCanvas()  
{  
    popup = window.open();
    popup.document.write("<br> <img src='"+canvas.toDataURL('png')+"'/>");
    popup.print();
}
```

The problem is, if I have only element on the canvas (say a circle) and press print, it will attempt to print out the entire canvas (3000 x 3000). Is there a way to change it so it only prints a certain section of the canvas or just the part where there are elements and not print out white space.

Thanks.

Comment: please comment if the answer below doesn't suit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer describes right approach. The main problem is to find boundaries. I get all image data and in two for-loops find boundaries:

```
function getCanvasBorders(canvas) {
  var topleft = {x: false, y: false};
  var botright = {x: false, y: false};

  for(var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
      if(!emptyPixel(context, x, y)) {
        if(topleft.x === false || x < topleft.x) {
          topleft.x = x;
        }
        if(topleft.y === false || y < topleft.y) {
          topleft.y = y;
        }
        if(botright.x === false || x > botright.x) {
          botright.x = x;
        }
        if(botright.y === false || y > botright.y) {
          botright.y = y;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {topleft: topleft, botright: botright};
}
```

SO snippets can't work with `document`, so here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/ojs882sq/).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a way to track and redraw the objects, you can do the following:

1. Calculate the max bounds that can contain all the objects
2. Create a new canvas the size of that bound
3. Draw in the region the bound represents using `drawImage()` with its clipping parameters, but offset -x and -y of the bound start position.

Print the temporary canvas instead.

Update: to find edges of image content only, assuming transparency for background, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255825/javascript-method-to-detect-area-of-a-png-that-is-not-transparent/23256220#23256220).