# How to crop a canvas in javascript to the desired height and width?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

Is there a better way to crop a javascript canvas than my own way, I find my way not very efficient. I want a png that doesn't have padding/extra space around the rendered text.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    Canvas = require('canvas');

    app.get('/test', function(req, res){

        let font = '40px serif',
                baseline = 'hanging',
                text = 'Hello World!';

      var canvas = new Canvas(),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.font = font;
        ctx.textBaseline = baseline;
        ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);

        let te = ctx.measureText(text);

        let width = te['actualBoundingBoxRight'];
        let height = te['actualBoundingBoxDescent'];

      var canvas2 = new Canvas(width, height),
      ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

        ctx2.font = font;
        ctx2.textBaseline = baseline;
        ctx2.fillText(text, 0, 0);

        res.send('<img src="' + canvas2.toDataURL() + '" />');

    });

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('app online on 3000');
    })
```

I measured the height and width of the text then made a new canvas that has these dimensions and i drew same exact text to achieved the desired result.

Comment: You could do it all from the same canvas.

Comment: Text metrics is currently limited. Chrome has full support,Edge requires *ExperimentalCanvasFeatures* flag set, and as far as I know the rest will only return the width. To crop the text of transparent edges use the method in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873660/3877726

Comment: @Blindman67 this is a node's implementation of Canvas2d API.